# Vim: Fire BufRead after BufReadCmd

Tags: vim

`BufReadCmd` is very useful for loading remote files, e.g. when you `:e protocol://some/file.txt`

The trick comes when you want to set `filetype=text` after you finish `BufReadCmd`. This is hard to do in the general case.

Ideally, all filetypes would be in `ftplugin/filetype.vim` and you could (potentially) fix this by cycling `filetype off | filetype on`. In practice, many filetypes are detected by the `BufRead` event. Furthermore, many plugins add functionality to certain filetypes using the `BufRead` event.

So if I want remote files to have the same functionality as local files I really need to fire the `BufRead` event after I'm finished handling the `BufReadCmd` event. How can I do this?

(Note: Yes, I know about scp and remote editing features. They can't be used here. I need something that works generally post-`BufReadCmd`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `:doautocmd` command for that:

```
:doauto BufRead
```

You can also specify what file name should be used for pattern matching by the autocommands in case that differs from what vim would detect by itself.